# How to prevent a DataTable on a web form being accessed from two different computers?

Tags: c#, webforms

I created a ‘Vacation Request’ where a user will see a calendar and select the dates they want to take vacation. When the user clicks on a date, that date is added to a DataTable. This DataTable is then bound to a GridView so the user can edit the number of hours taken for the day.

The issue I am having is when two people are logged into the website and using the Vacation Request at the same time. For example: UserA selects a date and everything looks fine. When UserB selects a date they also see UserA’s dates. If UserA selects another date, they also see what UserB has selected. UserA and UserB are on different computers. When they log into the site they are using different usernames.

Is using a DataTable causing this issue? Could it be how I declare the variables or functions? Any suggestions on how to accomplish this without using a DataTable?

```
public partial class Tvrtb : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //An arrayList used to color the calendar
    static ArrayList datesArray;
    static DataTable dtArray;
 }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
     {
       dtArray = new DataTable();
       dtArray.Columns.Add("VacReqNum", typeof(string));
       dtArray.Columns.Add("ReqDate", typeof(DateTime));
       dtArray.Columns.Add("ReqHours", typeof(string));
       dtArray.Columns.Add("VacReqID", typeof(string));
       dtArray.Columns.Add("VacReqDayID", typeof(string));
    }
}
protected void cl_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Is the date already selected? If so, unselect it
        DateTime dSelDate = default(DateTime);
        int index = -1;
        int tempIndex = -1;
        String nextDate = "";
        double vacHours = 0; 

        if (datesArray != null)
        {
            index = datesArray.IndexOf(cl.SelectedDate);
        }

        if (dtArray != null && dtArray.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow[] dr = dtArray.Select("ReqDate='" + cl.SelectedDate + "'");
            foreach (DataRow row in dr)
            {
                tempIndex = dtArray.Rows.IndexOf(row);
            }
            if (tempIndex > -1)
            {
                dtArray.Rows.RemoveAt(tempIndex);
                dtArray.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            datesArray.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        else
        {
            dSelDate = cl.SelectedDate;
            DayOfWeek day = dSelDate.DayOfWeek;

            datesArray.Add(dSelDate);
        }

        gvbind();
        //When a date is selected on the calendar then change the color of the cell so the user knows what dates are selected
        DisplaySelectedDates();
    }

    protected void gvbind()
    { 
        //Sort the array in the event the dates are not added in order
        datesArray.Sort();
        DataView dv = dtArray.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "ReqDate";
        DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
        dtArray = sortedDT;
        ViewState["selectedDates"] = datesArray;
        ViewState["vsDTArray"] = dtArray;

        if (dtArray.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
                gvDaysRequested.DataSource = dtArray;
                gvDaysRequested.DataBind();
                gvDaysRequested.Columns[2].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        }
        else
        {
            //Hide the calendar section
            cleb.Visible = false;
            //Show the New Vacation button
            NewVac.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the properties static?     static ArrayList datesArray;
    static DataTable dtArray;

Comment: When I changed it to private or public I get the following error:  'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Change to private DataTable dtArray = new DataTable();  You doing it in the load method which means you only have one webpage where each user should have there own webpage.  Each web connection need to be its own instance.  You have only one instance.  You also have issue with the cl_SelectionChanged which is being called when the class is being constructed before the Load occurs.  That is why DataTable is null.

Comment: @jdweng: thank you so much. I will make the changes you suggested. Can you give me a little more direction when you are talking about cl_SelectionChanged? How would I change this so it will do what I want?

Comment: What is cl?  Normally you would cast send to cl type and then check if cl is valid and just return if it is not valid.  For example if cl was a datatable check if the number of rows >= 0.  A datatable will have -1 rows until it is fully constructed.

Comment: @jdweng - cl is the calendar. When the user clicks a date on the calendar cl_SelectionChanged is called.

Comment: Should add at beginning of event if(cl == null) return;

Comment: @jdweng - I would like to mark your answer as the one that worked for me, but I am able. Thank you again.